# Center 3x3 images grid

Tags: html, css, dom

I created a webpage with 9 images total in 3 lines. Each line contains 3 images. I want to align all the images to the center of the page. Now the images align to the left. I tried to write text-align: center to the `<ul>` element with no success. Any ideas?

---

image1 image2 image3

image4 image5 image6

image7 image8 image9

---

html:

```
<body>

<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

css:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
li {
    background: url('img/house.jpg') center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top:33%;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li:nth-child(-n+3) {
    top:0;

}
li:nth-child(n+7) {
    top:66%;

}
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    left:33%;

}
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    left:66%;
}
```

Comment: any reason you don't want a table?

Comment: I would make the `li`s be `position: relative` and set them to be `display: inline-block`. Then you can set the parent element to have `text-align: center` which will center the images, and then you can have the images all be `width: 33%` to make sure there is only 3 per line

Comment: @DanielA.White because it isn't 1999?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Could you include an image of what you want the outcome should look like? Are you wanting all 9 image boxes to touch? Or do you just want everything to be evenly spaced away from the edges?

Comment: I want everything to be evenly spaced away from the edges. The images show NOT touch each other

Answer (score 0):

I suggest entirely different approach:

```
.item {
 margin:3px;
 background:url('http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/lookout
 /images/f/f4/Nice-house-  slc.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120526042017')
 center;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 width: 200px;
 height:200px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/XmoPQq

I have made the pics 100*100px, so they fit into the codepen screen.

Answer (score 0):

With this method you'd need to use breakpoints to define the margins dependent on the viewport width, but I think it's a simpler solution all in all.

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/200') center no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 5% 5% 5%;
    background-size: cover;
    list-style:none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution resembles that of **damiano celent** as I use flexbox too, but I also provided you with a basis for a responsive design (which I am guessing you will want later on).

This version also resizes smaller/larger images to fit in the box. The snippet is commented, but do comment if you want more support with this!

**BTW** Change your `ul` and `li` to `div` and you will see that it still works as expected. That's where class come into play...

```css
/* some globals with width and height
   so elements have a frame of reference */
html,body { 
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; cursor: default
}
body {
    max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: 0 auto
}
ul,li {
    list-style: none; padding: 0
}
.container-flex {
    /* Define as a flex container, centering its descendents */
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; align-items: center;
    height: 100%; width: auto
}
/* Any direct descendent will resize (not only UL works) */
.img-list-flex {
    /* Define as a flex container, centering its descendents */
    display: inline-flex; flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center; align-items: center; align-content: center;

    /* 1/3 of viewport width */
    width: calc(100vw/3); 
    height: calc(100vw/3); 
}
/* Any direct descendent will resize (not only LI works) */
.img-list-flex > * {
    background: #fafafa; border: 1px solid red;

    /* 1/3 of parent width minus 3 x 2 x 2px margin */
    width:  calc(100%/3 - 12px);
    height: calc(100%/3 - 12px); 
    
    /* Some space around the item */
    margin: 2px;

    /* Works for desktop, but needs media queries
       to set mobile/tablet/desktop limits */
     max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;

    /* chop excess data */
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* if an img-list-flex item contains an image, then */
.img-list-flex > * > img {
    min-width: 100%; /* stretch smaller images */
    max-width: 100%; /* shrink larger images */
    height: auto;    /* adjust image height accordingly */
}
```

```html
<div class="container-flex">
    <ul class="img-list-flex">
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/500"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```